# delete record from file using regex

Tags: regex

Remove all line started with `--`, inlucing line itself.

Input

```
111
222
--AAA
--VVV
OOO
```

Using expression

```
^--.*, ""
```

above expression removing lines but leaving empty libe over there

Current output

```
111
222


OOO
```

Expected output

```
111
222
OOO
```

Comment: What is the tool/language?

Comment: Testing in notepad++ but will be doing in Java

Comment: @LennyMarshal are you reading the whole file as a string? or you read each line in a string?

Comment: `^--.*\R*` or `^--.*\R?` will do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below expression:

```
^[ ]*--.*[\r]?[\n]?
```

Comment: It won't handle the last line. It won't work if line endings are CR only.

Comment: I have tested this in notepad++ and it works!